# Can i feed birds in my patio in Illinois

Tags: illinois

I am living in a town home in one of the North-west suburbs of Chicago. This is a newly constructed town-home with wooden decks in the patios of all the residents. The community is not yet fully construction completed.

My children like to feed birds and we put bird seeds in our patio. Now i see that since the day i started bird-feeding, I am starting to see bird droppings in both my immediate neighbor's patios.

I understand bird-feeding is unlawful in Chicago city area, but i am a bit unaware of the law in this place since i didnt see any boards that i usually see in Chicago.

I see one of my immediate neighbor has noticed this and he has installed the silver strips on the edges of his patio that keeps birds away from his place. My other neighbor has not yet moved in and might not be aware of this.

Now my question is - Am i allowed bird-feeding in my patio? What if in future one of my neighbors takes objection? Is there anything in Illinois law that protects my right of bird-feeding in my property?

Comment: This is very likely something that will depend on your local ordinances. Consult your town hall.

Comment: I would check your CCR paperwork because this is an issue that the HOA may have already thought about.

Comment: how about, outside the legality of doing so, don't be a menace to your neighbors, who likely don't want bird droppings on their units.

Answer (score 3):

There is no law against feeding birds, in Chicago or elsewhere in Illinois. The city does have a law against [*keeping* pigeons](https://codelibrary.amlegal.com/codes/chicago/latest/chicago_il/0-0-0-2640563) whereby

> It shall be unlawful for any person to import, sell, own, keep or
> otherwise possess any live pigeon within any area designated as a
> residence district under the Chicago Zoning Ordinance.

but this does not extend to feeding pigeons. Rumors may have gotten started because the DNR had recommended removing bird feeders for (bird) health reasons, but that is not a legal prohibition and anyhow has since expired.

Comment: I once had a landlord in Chicago ask me to remove my window-mounted bird feeder because the spilled birdseed was attracting rats.  I could imagine that some landlords might just blame a "city ordinance" in such a situation rather than get into an argument with a tenant, and a rumor could start that way.